# Amazon ubuntu ssh putty fail, WinScp works

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-ec2

I have two Amazon EC2 instances.
In both I can use `WinSCP` to connect using the putty public key ppk.
`Putty` used to work but now for some reason I can't SSH into these instances

> Username: ubuntu then the Public DNS
>   (IPv4)ec2-52-27-17-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

- I tried on two windows pc: both fail.
- I switched the firewall off - fail. 
  `ERROR:  --- Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) ---`
- I followed almost every tutorial from scratch but there is only so much you can do.

I would be very grateful if someone can help.

Comment: For anyone struggling with this I found the answer, the new version of putty keygen does not have SSH-2 only SSH-1, I recreated my ppk files with SSH-1 and voila !

Comment: Got one to work but not the other - still a mystery

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Remeber that you can [edit] your post when you want to update it... You have an answer, give it a look and in case upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate SSH-2/RSA key pair from puttygen, the radio button is now labeled RSA.

Put the public key in the authorized_keys file under the directory .ssh of your user. Remember to chmod 600 the autohorized_keys file and chmod 700 the .ssh directory